# JavaScript DateTime not working

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

```
function formatDate(dt) {
    //var date = new Date(dt);
    var date = new Date('2015-08-27 16:00:00'); alert(date.getMonth());
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + ampm;
    return date.getDate() + " " + date.getMonth() + " " + date.getFullYear() + " " + strTime;
}
```

I have tried to fetch Date and time. But I am getting `NaN` while alert `date.getMonth();`.
If I am removing time then this is working fine. But My date-time format dynamic. This is coming from the database like `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

I want to view my database date and time in the `27 Aug 2015 04:00:00 am/pm` format.

Comment: This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/gs6k7d16/

Comment: This is not working for me. :(  `NaN` is coming

Comment: Yes this is working in Chrome Browser but not working in Mozilla :( How to fix that?

Comment: It looks like you need to add a T before the time in firefox like this `'2015-08-27T16:00:00'`

Comment: the correct format is  `2015-08-27T16:00:00`  http://jsfiddle.net/gs6k7d16/1/

Comment: Chrome it works, but for mozilla you need to follow proper format check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: **Do not use the Date constructor to parse strings**. `new Date('2015-08-27 16:00:00')` will return any of 3 different values depending on the browser in use, which are you expecting?

Comment: @toby—Even with the T, IE 8 and lower will return NaN, ES5 browsers UTC and ECMAScript browsers local timezone of the system parsing the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format you are using (`2015-08-27 16:00:00`) is not the proper format for Firefox, though it works in Chrome. So, for this code to work properly on all browsers, it should not be used.

The below code works in **Firefox** and **Chrome**:

I've replaced the string variable date `-` with `/`. This format works for both Firefox and Chrome.

Another format that works in **Firefox** and **Chrome** is `1995-12-17T03:24:00` which includes `T` instead of `' '` (space).

However, the above format gives different value in Chrome and Firefox.

`new Date('2015-10-05T03:24:00'); // Returns Mon Oct 05 2015 08:54:00 GMT+0530 (IST) in Chrome`

`new Date('2015-10-05T03:24:00'); // Returns 2015-10-04T21:54:00.000Z in Firefox`

```js
var date1 = '2015-08-20 09:38:20';
var date1Updated = new Date(date1.replace(/-/g,'/'));
alert(date1Updated.getMonth());
```

Comment: Programming by trial and error isn't a good strategy. Parsing of the date format in the OP by the Date constructor is implementation dependent and may return any of 3 different values. A good answer includes an explanation of why the error occurs, how to it and why the fix works.

Comment: Updated answer. Thanks for you suggestions...I'll keep in mind for future answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 var strDate =  addZero(d.getDate()) + "/" + addZero((d.getMonth() + 1))+"/"  +d.getFullYear();
        alert("strDate :"+strDate)
        return strDate;
    }
    function addZero(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`getMonth()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp) method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.

**Note**: January is 0, February is 1, and so on.
you need to add one like `getMonth() + 1`.

```js
function formatDate(dt) {
    //var date = new Date(dt);
    var date = new Date('2015-08-27 16:00:00'); 
    //alert(date.getMonth() + 1);
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + ampm;
    return date.getDate() + " " + (date.getMonth() + 1) + " " + date.getFullYear() + " " + strTime;
}
alert(formatDate());
```

Comment: Go through the question and **comments** ozil!

Answer (score 0):

In firefox `'2015-08-27 16:00:00'` is an invalid date.

Your options are

```
var today = new Date();
var birthday = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
var birthday = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');
var birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17);
var birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17, 3, 24, 0);
```

In your case you're missing the `T` before the time

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: There is nothing invalid about the string. It may not conform to ISO 8601, however there is no requirement for ECMAScript implementations to correctly parse  `'December 17, 1995 03:24:00'` either.

Comment: @RobG I did mention in firefox, maybe i should have used `datestring` but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid date format, It seems Chrome handle this situation but firefox not.

```
 new Date('2015-08-27 16:00:00') // Invalid format
 new Date('2015-08-27T16:00:00') // Correct Format With T
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work in firefox

In firefox `2015-08-27 16:00:00`isn't valid. 
To be valid it has to be `2015-08-27T16:00:00`.
To make it valid in firefox, the easiest solution would be

```
function formatDate(dt) {
    //var date = new Date(dt);
    var sampleDate = "2015-08-27 16:00:00"; // Your sample date as string
    var another = sampleDate.replace(' ', 'T');// Change here. Replaced the empty space with the 'T' to make it work in firefox
    var date = new Date(another); alert(date.getMonth()); // Using your date to create new Date object
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + ampm;
    return date.getDate() + " " + date.getMonth() + " " + date.getFullYear() + " " + strTime;
}
```

Hope i was helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Parsing strings using the Date constructor is largely implementation dependent. Only one format of string is specified as being supported by the specification and that changed to some extent between ES5 and ECMAScript 2015.

Your best option is to manually parse the string, either using your own function or a library. The following will suit if the string is consistently the format in the OP and the timezone is UTC:

```js
/*  parse dates of format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss 
**  e.g. 2015-08-27 16:00:00
** 
**  @param {string} s - Date string in format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
**  @returns {Date}   - String as Date assuming UTC
**
**  Does not validate that the string is valid date or time
**/
function parseDate (s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]));
}

document.write(parseDate('2015-08-27 16:00:00'));
```